# How to add zapcore.NewMultiWriteSyncer in zap.Config using golang zap log project

Tags: go, go-zap

I am working on a log package and hope to configure whether to use *log rotation* through switches.

Previous code did not support log rotate

```golang
// using zap.Config and cannot log rotate

// Build constructs a global zap logger from the Config and Options.
func (o *Options) Build() error {
    var zapLevel zapcore.Level
    if err := zapLevel.UnmarshalText([]byte(o.Level)); err != nil {
        zapLevel = zapcore.InfoLevel
    }
    encodeLevel := zapcore.CapitalLevelEncoder
    if o.Format == consoleFormat && o.EnableColor {
        encodeLevel = zapcore.CapitalColorLevelEncoder
    }

    zc := &zap.Config{
        Level:             zap.NewAtomicLevelAt(zapLevel),
        Development:       o.Development,
        DisableCaller:     o.DisableCaller,
        DisableStacktrace: o.DisableStacktrace,
        Sampling: &zap.SamplingConfig{
            Initial:    100,
            Thereafter: 100,
        },
        Encoding: o.Format,
        EncoderConfig: zapcore.EncoderConfig{
            MessageKey:     "message",
            LevelKey:       "level",
            TimeKey:        "timestamp",
            NameKey:        "logger",
            CallerKey:      "caller",
            StacktraceKey:  "stacktrace",
            LineEnding:     zapcore.DefaultLineEnding,
            EncodeLevel:    encodeLevel,
            EncodeTime:     timeEncoder,
            EncodeDuration: milliSecondsDurationEncoder,
            EncodeCaller:   zapcore.ShortCallerEncoder,
            EncodeName:     zapcore.FullNameEncoder,
        },
        OutputPaths:      o.OutputPaths,
        ErrorOutputPaths: o.ErrorOutputPaths,
    }
    
    logger, err := zc.Build(zap.AddStacktrace(zapcore.PanicLevel))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    zap.RedirectStdLog(logger.Named(o.Name))
    zap.ReplaceGlobals(logger)

    return nil
}
```

Now I hope to support rotation. I checked the relevant information and found that it can be rotated in the following way

```golang
//   logrotate.log
syncer :=zapcore.NewMultiWriteSyncer(zapcore.AddSync(os.Stdout), zapcore.AddSync(lumberJackLogger))   
// lumberJackLogger encapsulate lumberjack.Logger

core := zapcore.NewCore(
        zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(zap.NewProductionEncoderConfig()),
        syncer,
        logLevel,
    )
logger := zap.New(core, zap.AddCaller(), zap.AddStacktrace(zap.ErrorLevel))
```

I hope to change `OutputPaths` and `ErrorOutputPaths` into the form of `logrorate.go` when starting rotation based on config.

Just like the following pseudo code

```golang
if ! o.EnableRorate
  zap.Config{...OutputPaths,ErrorOutputPaths}
else
   zap.config add zapcore.NewMultiWriteSyncer
```

Please tell me what I need to do to achieve my expectations.  Looking forward to your reply

PS: I hope that other configurations besides o.OutputPaths and o.ErrorOutputPaths can still be used under the new solution.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a weird mix of concerns having a logger package do log rotation. The life cycle of an app is almost always less than the life cycle of log files on disk, and logging to disk is just *one* of many logger outputs. Take a look at `zap.Sink`. Nowhere is a file even remotely implied, it's basically just an `io.Writer`.

If you're not in control over the machine on which your app runs, then ask your platform person to introduce `logrotate` to the system. This is a pretty stable tool from the 80s, still active and used all over the place. It will allow you to write, care-free from zap, and let `logrotate` care about size/lines/whatever.

It could be that we have different interpretations of what "log rotation" means, and I have interpreted it to be a constraint on log file size, and some archival function (logrotate gzips by default). If this differs from your interpretation, then forgive me.

Answer (score 1):

I searched and found that it can be achieved using zap.WrapCore.

```
// hack replace zap config build core with lumberjack logger
func (o *Options) replaceLogCore(conf zap.Config) zap.Option {
    var enc zapcore.Encoder
    // Copy paste from zap.Config.buildEncoder.
    switch conf.Encoding {
    case jsonFormat:
        enc = zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(conf.EncoderConfig)
    case consoleFormat:
        enc = zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(conf.EncoderConfig)
    default:
        panic("unknown encoding")
    }

    logSyncer := zapcore.AddSync(&lumberjack.Logger{
        Filename:   o.RotateLogPath,
        MaxSize:    o.RotateMaxSize, //MB
        MaxBackups: o.RotateMaxBackups,
        MaxAge:     o.RotateMaxAge, //days
        LocalTime:  o.RotateEnableLocalTime,
        Compress:   o.RotateEnableCompress,
    })

    return zap.WrapCore(func(zapcore.Core) zapcore.Core {
        return zapcore.NewCore(enc, logSyncer, conf.Level)
    })
}
```

[reference](https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-tablestore-go-sdk/blob/aefad2866933e441f98dac09f39f14bb54507132/tunnel/config.go#L128)